# Jenkins crashes randomly with no warning

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm running Jenkins as a service on a Ubuntu server and it has been recently crashing.  My server has 512 MB of RAM with 256 MB allocated to Jenkins.  I checked the logs, but no traces of crashing have been recorded in there, so I suspect that Jenkins terminates immediately in each crash.

I recently tested the uptime of Jenkins, and it crashes between 2 to 15 minutes of being online.  I also tested the memory used, and Jenkins uses 120 MB of RAM to 160 MB of RAM.  Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: I'm using Oracle JDK 7.

Comment: Which JVM are you using? Are there any hs_err_pid*.log files lying around?

Comment: I'm using Oracle JDK 7.

Comment: No, I can't find any hs_err_pid*.log files around.

Comment: Check /var/log/messages for something like the oom killer some Linux distros ship with.

Comment: Try running it from command line, and see if you get anything more helpful there.